# How to print the url and the filename from image field in views-view-unformatted.tpl.php in Drupal 7?

Tags: views, media

I tried using this code, but it does not work.

```
<?php print $node->field_slider_image['und'][0]['filename']; ?>
```

Comment: use dpm() function to display the render array, then you might see the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

The full file object isn't necessarily loaded into the node object, you could try loading it manually and grabbing the filename/URL that way:

```
$file = file_load($node->field_slider_image['und'][0]['fid']);

// Filename
print $file->filename;

// URI e.g. public://image.jpg
print $file->uri;

// URL e.g. /sites/default/files/image.jpg
print file_create_url($file->uri);
```